# Entity Framework add property to partial class that will get model or list of models from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, partial-classes

I have added a property to a partial class of a model. This property will retrieve a model from database according to property value.

Example:

```
class movie
{
    int language;
}

partial movie 
{
    public Language SpokenLanguage
    {
       get
       {
          var currLang = db.Languages.Where(ml => ml.ID == this.language).FirstOrDefault();
          return currLang;
       }
   }
}
```

Is this approach will affect application performance when I retrieve a list of movies?

If so what is the equivalent and better performance?

Comment: No, that field won't be considered by EF, but why do you do such thing? You can add this relation in EF, why do you do it manually?

Comment: I have a column with comma seperated Ids value

Comment: Wow, it's pretty wrong. It isn't right way to create relations between tables. You should have a link table for many-to-many relation. Read about that kind of relationship and how to properly do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF will ignore the SpokenLanguage property in your case.

However, you can make EF retrieve the SpokenLanguage using a INNER JOIN by adding a relation in your model between the two tables.

You can also make it retrieve the SpokenLanguage lazily (on demand)-it will actually make a better version on what you wrote, but if you are sure you want to print the language label in your view, it's better to retrieve it using a INNER JOIN.